# UIMenuController doesn't update menu for first time

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I have UITextView on which I want to add highlight as custom menu item. I have registered to following notification `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification`.

The method for the notification is something like this:

```
if textIsHighlighted {
    let highlightMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Highlight", action: Selector("highlightText"))
    UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = [highlightMenuItem]
}
else {
    let highlightMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Dehighlight", action: Selector("highlightText"))
    UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = [highlightMenuItem]
}
```

Although the first time the menucontroller fails to update even though it executes the part of code. It shows the last value. Where should I write this part of code as I feel that during willShow menuController it's already created and thus fails to update.

Comment: You need to call update method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you've solved this by now, but I've just figured this one out myself:
Other answers have said you can update the menu items by adding it when the `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification` is called, but this wasn't working for me (iOS 9, Swift 2).

Instead I implemented the `UITextView` delegate method: `textViewDidChangeSelection` and set the relevant menu items there:

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(textView: UITextView) {
    if self.currentSelectionIsInHighlightedRange() {
        self.setUpUnhighlightMenuItem()
    } else {
        self.setUpHighlightMenuItem()
    }
}

private func currentSelectionIsInHighlightedRange() -> Bool {
    let allHighlightedRanges = self.document.highlightedRanges()

    let selectedTextRange = self.documentView.textView.selectedRange

    for range in allHighlightedRanges {
        let intersectionRange = NSIntersectionRange(range, selectedTextRange)
        if intersectionRange.length > 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks. This issue is too old so I don't remember the problem now but hope your solution is right I'm accepting it.

Comment: I encountered the exact same problem where my UIMenuItems are not updated immediately. Even calling .update() does not address this. But the intuition here solves my issue, which is to add the menu items before it needs to be used.